# How to remove ' from a list with several items

Tags: python, formatting

Here is the code

```
x = (([(''+ 'e[' + str(i) + ']') for i in range(11)]))
print(x)
['e[0]', 'e[1]', 'e[2]', 'e[3]', 'e[4]', 'e[5]', 'e[6]', 'e[7]', 'e[8]', 'e[9]', 'e[10]']
```

In the end I want the format as TUPLE
To remove  `''` you could convert this to a string:

```
y = ', '.join(x)
print(y)
e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], e[4], e[5], e[6], e[7], e[8], e[9], e[10]
```

Comment: are you trying to convert your list to string? (I also doubt that above code is not what you desire. May be you want list and access by index? But your end up creating list of strings?)

Comment: Please elaborate on the intended output.

Comment: Wouldn't you just set the `range` to 11? (`(([(''+ 'e[' + str(i) + ']') for i in range(11)]))`)

Comment: Use `range(11)`??

Comment: intended output with the single apostrophes

Comment: @SangramRout are you trying to change the data structure or how it's displayed to the user? Both things are possible, but very different things.

Comment: apologies, @SangramRout I did not meant to change the questions.

Comment: I would like to keep the format as Tuple in the final outcome. When I convert it into tuple it gets save as individual characters

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?:

```
x = (([(''+ 'e[' + str(i) + ']') for i in range(11)]))
```

x looks like this:
['e[0]',
'e[1]',
'e[2]',
'e[3]',
'e[4]',
'e[5]',
'e[6]',
'e[7]',
'e[8]',
'e[9]',
'e[10]']

To remove the `''` perhaps:

```
y = ', '.join(x)
print(y)
e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], e[4], e[5], e[6], e[7], e[8], e[9], e[10]
```

To make the string looks like a tuple:

```
z = '('+', '.join(x)+')'
print(z)
(e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], e[4], e[5], e[6], e[7], e[8], e[9], e[10])
```

Comment: I want to remove the quotes inside. I have done it with a single element as  j= (j+ 'e[' + str(1) + ']'). However, I want to use it in the loop now

Comment: thanks @rafael Valero. I spend 6 hours on this today and couldn't figure out

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes are there because each element of the list `x` is a string - if you want to produce a string *representation* of `x` with single quotes omitted, the following should work:

```
str(x).replace("'","") # == '[e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], ..., e[10]]'
```

If you're looking to display `x` as a tuple, you could convert it first as well - e.g:

```
str(tuple(x)).replace("'","") # == '(e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3],..., e[10])'
```